# How do I associate the Windows key with GNOME menu in Fedora?

Tags: fedora, gnome

There is a similar question:
[How to associate the Fedora Start menu with the Windows keyboard?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/970/how-to-associate-the-fedora-start-menu-with-the-windows-keyboard)

but it's for KDE 4. Can someone post equivalent steps for GNOME?

Answer (score 3):

For Fedora 14 and prior (Gnome 2.x), you can run the following from a terminal:

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/metacity/global_keybindings/panel_main_menu --type string "Super_L"
```

This will set the left Windows key to launch the Applications menu.

If you prefer a GUI: Applications -> System Tools -> Configuration Editor.  (This isn't usually installed by default, so you may have to `yum install gconf-editor`.)  Browse to `/apps/metacity/global_keybindings/`, and set `Super_L` as the value of `panel_main_menu`.

`Super_L` is the left Windows key, `Super_R` is the right Windows key.

More info on the Super key [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_key_%28keyboard_button%29#Linux_and_BSD)

Answer (score 1):

Fedora uses GNOME 3 since version 15.

With GNOME 3, the closest to a "Start menu" is the "Activities overview".

The default keyboard shortcut is ALT+F1, which can be overridden in System Settings:

System settings → Keyboard → Shortcuts → System → "Show the activities overview".

With older versions of Fedora (GNOME 2),  the same (default) keyboard shortcut brings up the "Applications" menu, but it can not be overridden.